# How to make draggable column in HTML5 with 5 seconds refresh rate?

Tags: html, backbone.js, html-table

I am making a website which is loading data from ajax webservice call and populating it in html tables and this data gets refreshed in every 5 seconds. I have achieved this using lazy loading in Backbone JS. So when javascript timer fires in every 5 seconds it makes ajax call and it reloads the template which contains the table thus showing new data.

```
this.metrices.fetch({
            url : (isLocal) ? ('js/jsons/agent.json') : (prev_this.url + '/agentstat'),
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            contentType: "application/json",
            })
            .done(function() {  
            }); 


this.$("#agentMetrics").html(this.agentTemplate({
            agents: this.metrices.toJSON()
        }));
```

And the #agentMetrics template is like this

```
      <table class="table_class js-table-deskop" id="agent" style = "width:100%">
     <tr class="">
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-0 js-agentPref-0">Names</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-1">State</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-2">Skill</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-8">Center</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-9">Lan Id</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-10">Login Id</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-11">Manager</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-12">Site</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-13">Team Leader</th>
        <th class="js-table-agent js-agentPref-14">Workgroup</th>
     </tr>
     {{#each agents}}
     <tr >
        <td class="th1 js-agentPref-0">{{name}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-1 js-state-agent" >{{state}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-2 js-skill-agent">{{dispSkill}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-8">{{center}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-9 js-lanid-agent">{{lanId}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-10">{{loginId}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-11">{{manager}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-12">{{site}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-13">{{teamLead}}</td>
        <td class="js-alert js-agentPref-14">{{workGroup}}</td>
     </tr>
     {{/each}}
  </table>
```

Now the problem is that I have a new requirement where I have to make these columns resizable and swappable i.e their width could be changed by dragging and can columns can be swapped like it can be done in Adobe flex.
This is where it gets tricky as what ever I used since the template gets refreshed in 5 seconds so it is not able to hold this selection is there any plugin to achieve this which supports retention of this preference dragging or swapping. Or can I some how prevent loading of template, any suggession

Comment: Are you "reloading" the entire table every time or just the contents of each cell?

Comment: @AdamJeffers entire table is reloaded as I don't know how many rows that can be returned

Comment: *"How to make draggable column in HTML5 .."* is not really your problem... You don't seem to be waiting for the ajax call to finish before updating the template... so that is probably not the working code... Please take some time to add a meaningful title so that future readers can find it, and add a [mcve], if not real working code when asking questions. The community is solving your issues for free, at least give that much back to community see [ask] :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a data binding library like [rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/).

Once you bind your view with rivets, changes in the model/collection will be updated in `DOM` by rivets without replacing the entire `DOM`.

If new records are added, new `DOM` element will be inserted in the respective position without altering the existing ones.

Below is a small demo taken from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069020/2333214) of mine:

```js
rivets.adapters[':'] = {
  observe: function(obj, keypath, callback) {
    obj.on('change:' + keypath, callback)
  },
  unobserve: function(obj, keypath, callback) {
    obj.off('change:' + keypath, callback)
  },
  get: function(obj, keypath) {
    return obj.get(keypath)
  },
  set: function(obj, keypath, value) {
    obj.set(keypath, value)
  }
}
var data = [{
  name: "john",
  age: 10
}, {
  name: "joseph",
  age: 11
}, {
  name: "joy",
  age: 12
}]

var userCollection = new Backbone.Collection(data);
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.render()
  },
  render: function() {
    rivets.bind(this.el, {
      users: this.collection
    });
  }
});
var userView = new View({
  el: '#user-list',
  collection: userCollection
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.8.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<ul id='user-list'>
  <li rv-each-user="users.models">
    <input type="text" rv-value="user:age"/>
    <span>{user:name}</span><span> {user:age}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```